# Mips Assembly Language Convert C conditional

Tags: mips

How to convert following C conditional statement in MIPS?
if (A<=B || B == D)
where suppose A is stored in $t2, B in $t4, D in $t6

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers

Compare A and B using `sltu` or `slt` instruction (they are not the interchangeable). If the condition is satisfied, then that's all (lazyness). Its probably easier using these instructions to check if `B < A` act on that.

If not,  compare B and D using the `bneq` or `beq` instruction. Choose one whether you want to fallthrough or branch to the `if's` body.